# Слить один массив с другим

Tags: php

1 array

```
  Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 5
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 4
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 3
    )
)
```

2 array

```
 Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0463.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0463
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0465.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0465
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0459.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0459
    )
 )
```

нужно получить такого вида

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0463.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0463
        [quantity] => 5
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0465.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0465
        [quantity] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => /image/data/barcode/SKPAK-1006-0459.png
        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0459
        [quantity] => 3
    )
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом `array_merge` сливаем в цикле элементы из обоих массивов с соответствующими индексами в один массив и добавляем его как элемент в новый массив.

```
$new_arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
    $new_arr[$i] = array_merge($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/305a88faf7e0e7058194b03653c13d716275c06f).

Как подсказывают в комментариях, цикл можно вообще убрать:

```
$new_arr = array_map('array_merge', $arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: `$new_arr = array_map('array_merge', $arr1, $arr2);`

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, дополнил

Answer (score 0):

```
// дополнение второго массива элементами первого согласно индексам.
$i = 0;
foreach($a2 as &$el) {
    $el += $a1[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

[пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea0853692ecd104f5a9db100ba3bb7a17f3f4833)